# Pass object through NodeJS to PHP

Tags: php, node.js, object

I´m trying to pass object with two keys/values and I want to read it on the other side when I make Apache connect to it.

My nodejs server looks like so:

```
var sWeather = {"url1": "something", "url2": "another"};
var oWeather = JSON.stringify(sWeather);
console.log(sWeather);


var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end(sWeather+'\n');
}).listen(1340, '#');
console.log('Server running at http://###/');
```

Now I´m really new to nodejs and I have tried alot of thing so I´m not sure if I need to stringify the `sWeather` before I send it away.

My PHP file is like so:

```
<?php
$responseFromNode = file_get_contents("IP address");
var_dump($responseFromRuby);
```

For now I get `string '[object Object]` on my webpage because of `var_dump`.

I've tried doing something like

```
$url1 = $responseFromNode->url1
```

or

```
$url1 = $responseFromNode['url1']
```

I would just like to access both of the urls as a string so I can store it.

Any tips would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if this is a typo, but you have `var_dump($responseFromRuby)`.. don't you mean `$responseFromNode` ?

Comment: He's probably using `var_dump` to see if he's getting what he expects from the Node server. As for a how to do this, make your Node side like a rest API, serve JSON, use cURL in PHP to make a request to your Node app. From there it'll be pretty easy.

Comment: You should also change your content type: `res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`oWeather` is the JSON string. Change

```
res.end(sWeather+'\n');
```

To

```
res.end(oWeather+'\n');
```

Then the PHP side has to decode the JSON

```
$responseFromNode = json_decode( file_get_contents("IP address") );
```

**Notes:**

- You should also change your content type: `res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});`, as mentioned by [Brian Glaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/830247/brian-glaz)
- Your variable names are inverted:

  - `oWeather` should be the object
  - `sWeather` should be the JSON string

Comment: Hi Juan, thank you for reply, it helped me exactly like I needed. And thanks for pointing out the inverted var names. I'll mark your post answered when I can :)